# How to fill up the fields in CreateView itself

Tags: python-3.7, django-2.1

I'm Creating a project and i have one doubt, so the site if for a support center where a the django project logs a case for the user after user fill out a general form.

So i have created a model name Case and it has fields like case_number, email and all that.

Now, in views.py i am using CBV CreateView to create save the userform and create a case number simple.

Where i am stuck at is, the case number which is a 10 digit string field needs to be randomly created, but how do i store it after customer is done with filling the form?

because whatever ill mention in fields will show up as a input for customer and case_number is not what i want customer to fill it, it should be auto generated.

I believe it can be done simply by:-

r2 = [random.randint(0, 10),random.randint(0, 10),random.randint(0, 10),random.randint(0, 10),random.randint(0, 10),random.randint(0, 10),random.randint(0, 10),random.randint(0, 10),random.randint(0, 10),random.randint(0, 10)]

case_number = (''.join(str(x) for x in r2))

and in CBV CreateView will let me create a number randomly and save it but i want this to be done at the backend so i cant mention it in create view,

This is just doubt, i have tried it yet.

## models.py

```
class Case:
    case_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    issue=models.TextField()
    product=models.CharField(max_field=100)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('case:single')
```

## Views.py

```
class CaseCreation(CreateView):
    model=Case
    fields=('issue', 'product')
    r2=[random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10)]

    self.case_number = (''.join(str(x) for x in r2))
```

The Expected result is that i want randomly a 10 digit number to get crated for customer and get saved in the db

DB is sql lite3.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so just to let you guys know i finally came up with an answer,

I defined the logic of creating the cases in models.py as below.

```
def case_generation(self):
    r2=[random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10)]
    self.case_number = (''.join(str(x) for x in r2))
    self.save()
```

Now in views.py i defined a function and called the function defined in models.py and save.

```
@login_required
def case_number_generation(request, pk):
    case = get_object_or_404(Case, pk=pk)
    case.case_generation()
    return redirect("cases:single_pk", pk=case.pk)
```

in between this i defined the urls.py such that one the user generates the case, the functions will be called by itself.

If your interested to look into the full code, no worries let me know ill post it here if required. ;)